# Select stream network within a fixed distance from a point

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1

Is there a tool out there that would allow me to select a portion of stream network that is within a fixed distance from a specific point on that network?

In the example below, there is an acclimation site on Palmer Creek (green dot).  I want to be able to select all portions of my stream network that are within 4 steam miles (not euclidean) of that point.  In the example below I manually selected the stream segments within 4 miles.

Is there a tool to automate this process, as I have upward of 25 points?

[image]

Comment: How would you deal with loops? With one side you could travel further because it is more sinuous than the other yet end up at exactly the same location.

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is a way to automate it, if you have access to the Network Analyst Extension. Here is how I would approach it:

1. Use your stream lines as the network, and build a [network dataset](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/extensions/network-analyst/exercise-1-creating-a-network-dataset.htm)
2. Run the [service area tool](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/guide-books/extensions/network-analyst/service-area.htm) to build a polygon that encompasses the area within 4 miles of your point. This will be "stream-miles" not Euclidean distance. The result is a polygon
3. Use the polygon to split the lines into segments (you could use a number of tools mentioned [here](http://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000012699))
4. Select those line segments that were cut